# multiple input of different data type from a single client to server (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, audio, server, client

Good day.

I am sending a string of user name (so I know the following file belongs to which user) then followed by stream of array of bytes(for audio) from android client to server running in java. 
I think of opening different ports but because the server is running in a private network so if I want to open more ports then I need to add more port forwarding function which is quite silly.

I able to send string of username and arrays of bytes separately but when audio file after user name, the audio file will be sped up.

server.java

```
while (true) {
            Socket socket = listener.accept();
            try {

                InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader inFileN = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                if (fileName==null) {
                    fileName=inFileN.readLine();
                    File dir = new File("/home/xxx/Documents/" + fileName);
                    dir.mkdirs();
                    }


                String filePath =  "/home/xxx/Documents/"+fileName+"/voice8K16bitmono.pcm";
                FileOutputStream os = null;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int count;

                try {
                    os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
                {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }

            } finally {
                socket.close();
            }
```

client side for writing string of user name

```
try {
        s = new Socket("localhost", 9090);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.print(userID);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

client side for writing audio file under some condition

```
try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 9090);
            outToServer = s.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (isRecording) {
            recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
            detectSilence(sData, threshold);
            try {
                byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);
                //os.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);
                outToServer.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Or is there any other better way to use if I want to sending multiple data types from a single client?

ps: I have not implemented multi-threaded server at this point because I want to make sure it works with a single user first

Thank you.